# Monitoring Kubernetes with Grafana: lots of missing data with latest Prometheus version

Tags: kubernetes, grafana, prometheus

I have a working Kubernetes cluster that I want to monitor with Grafana.

I have been trying out many dashboards from https://grafana.com/dashboards but they all seem to have some problems: it looks like there's a mismatch between the Prometheus metric names and what the dashboard expects.

Eg if I look at this recently released, quite popular dashboard: https://grafana.com/dashboards/5309/revisions

I end up with many "holes" when running it:

[image: grafana dashboard with missing values]

Looking into the panel configuration, I see that the issues come from  small key changes, eg `node_memory_Buffers` instead of `node_memory_Buffers_bytes`.

Similarly the dashboard expects `node_disk_bytes_written` when Prometheus provides `node_disk_written_bytes_total`.

I have tried out a *lot* of Kubernetes-specific dashboards and I have the same problem with almost all of them.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Prometheus node exporter changed a lot of the metric names in the 0.16.0 version to conform to new naming conventions.

From https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter/releases/tag/v0.16.0:

> **Breaking changes**
>
> This release contains major breaking changes to metric names. Many
>   metrics have new names, labels, and label values in order to conform
>   to current naming conventions.
>
> - Linux node_cpu metrics now break out `guest` values into separate
>     metrics.
> - Many counter metrics have been renamed to `include _total`.
> - Many metrics have been renamed/modified to include
>     base units, for example `node_cpu` is now `node_cpu_seconds_total`.

See also the [upgrade guide](https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter/blob/v0.16.0/docs/V0_16_UPGRADE_GUIDE.md). One of its suggestion is to use [compatibility rules](https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter/blob/v0.16.0/docs/example-16-compatibility-rules.yml) that will create duplicate metrics with the old names.

Otherwise use version 0.15.x until the dashboards are updated, or fix them!